# How can I use a 3G usb dongle as a wireless antenna to access internet?

Tags: wireless, usb, internet

I have an old 3g usb dongle I used to connect to the internet, the SIM card has expired many years ago but I recall the dongle could connect to wifi.

I have resurrected my old desktop that has no wireless network card so my question is, can I connect to wifi networks with my usb dongle? And if I can, how do I configure it to be an antenna instead of a 3g dongle?

I'm fairly new and inexperienced and IT so be patient.

EDITED:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 02 Apr 2016 03:10 WEST +0100

Booted last: 02 Apr 2016 00:09 WEST +0100

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-56-generic #62~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 11 11:03:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2a94]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 006: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 19d2:1405 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 04f2:0841 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 12d1:1003 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E220 HSDPA Modem / E230/E270/E870 HSDPA/HSUPA Modem
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

cfg80211              524288  0 

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'usb0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.136  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'usb0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:105676 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:75698 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:114430054 (114.4 MB)  TX bytes:8136111 (8.1 MB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'virbr0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 usb0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search 208.67.220.220 208.67.222.222

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1345     1  0 00:09 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: ttyUSB1 --------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Mobile Broadband (GSM)
  Driver:            option1
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no

  Capabilities:

- Device: usb0  [Wired connection 2] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            cdc_ether
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'usb0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.136
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1
    DNS:             208.67.222.222
    DNS:             208.67.220.220

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<MAC 'usb0' [IF]>,<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>,

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Lisbon (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

virbr0    no frequency information.

usb0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

virbr0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

usb0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-56-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     EF182B558008C23DD85EF03
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-56-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        0D:22:80:B1:1C:0F:54:77:D5:8C:80:D7:06:21:62:5D:AE:0F:BC:8D
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

mount -a

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   10.153607] cdc_ether 2-3:1.0 usb0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:1d.7-3, CDC Ethernet Device, <MAC 'usb0' [IF]>
[   21.513349] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link down
[   21.513386] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   21.525471] cdc_ether 2-3:1.0 usb0: kevent 12 may have been dropped (repeated 3 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I've done as requested and have posted the results, hope I can get some help and that the modem can connect! PS: It's the HDSPA Huawei modem I'm trying to user as wifi antenna

Comment: I don't think you can convert your mobile broadband modem into a WiFi network client. Even though they both use antennas and partially rely on the same encoding principles they use different communications protocols and radio frequencies. It is theoretically possible to have a modem and a WiFi adapter inside the same USB device case but they would need to present themselves as multiple USB devices to the host system whereas I can see only one relevant entry in the `lsusb` output. I'll convert this into an answer if this question is re-opened.

Comment: … make that two relevant entries but both are mobile broadband modems.

Comment: the modem has 2 usb jacks, one name "assistant power" was off.... could it be the missing second usb device you mentioned?

I ran the network diagnostics again and have reedited the result in the original question.

Sorry for my noobility and taking so much of your time...

Comment: I just rechecked confirming with your answer, basically it doesn't work... Damn....

Answer (score -1):

I assume you're on Ubuntu. Configuring your 3G dongle to connect to a WiFi network, in many cases, requires the use of the official software that came with the dongle.

This software, again, in many cases, works only on Windows. You may install the dongle software in Ubuntu via Wine, but I do not see everything working as normal.

It is therefore, through the software interface, that you can manipulate settings, such as connecting to a WiFi network, or even configuring the use of the dongle SD Card slot.

You may run the software in a virtual Windows environment to see the settings of the dongle software if it supports connecting to WiFi and if there're configuration options for that.

Comment: -1 Managing hardware through Wine almost never works if the host system doesn't have working drivers for it.